# Voronoi Diagram Algorithm for Geo Locations?

Tags: machine-learning, python, distance

As per my Understanding:

**Voronoi diagram:** A Voronoi diagram is a simple concept, and it's based on the minimal distance needed to reach a landmark. If you need to go to a metro station, the most natural algorithm is going to the nearest one.

Or

**Voronoi Diagram:** On a plane, for a set of sites (points in that 2D space with similar properties) the Voronoi diagram partitions the space based on the minimal distance to each site.

**General Python Implementation:**

This implementation takes in a list of points, each point being a tuple and returns a dictionary consisting of all the points at a given site.

> ```
> from PIL import Image
> import random
> import math
> def generate_voronoi_diagram(width, height, num_cells):
>     image = Image.new("RGB", (width, height))
>     putpixel = image.putpixel
>     imgx, imgy = image.size
>     nx = []
>     ny = []
>     nr = []
>     ng = []
>     nb = []
>     for i in range(num_cells):
>         nx.append(random.randrange(imgx))
>         ny.append(random.randrange(imgy))
>         nr.append(random.randrange(256))
>         ng.append(random.randrange(256))
>         nb.append(random.randrange(256))
>     for y in range(imgy):
>         for x in range(imgx):
>             dmin = math.hypot(imgx-1, imgy-1)
>             j = -1
>             for i in range(num_cells):
>                 d = math.hypot(nx[i]-x, ny[i]-y)
>                 if d < dmin:
>                     dmin = d
>                     j = i
>             putpixel((x, y), (nr[j], ng[j], nb[j]))
>     image.save("VoronoiDiagram.png", "PNG")
>         image.show()
> generate_voronoi_diagram(500, 500, 25)
> ```

[More Voronoi Diagram Implementations](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)

**Case**

Imagine a city, where a fire is declared. Emergency services need to send a fire truck to this place. If there are N fire stations, what fire truck should be sent?

[image]

The nearest fire truck is in the light green Voronoi Area, the same area as the fire. No other truck can reach any light green point faster than this truck.

**My questions are**

> How to implement the Voronoi diagram for geolocations like places or lat, longs. As in the above cases.
>
> Are there any approaches/techniques that we can consider for similar cases?
>
> **Can anyone be kind enough to walk me through it?**